# Can't open Drawer react native

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-native-navigation, drawer, react-navigation-drawer

I created createDrawerNavigator. But when call  "props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())" nothing show. Here is my code.

**MenuNavigator.js**

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import Login from "../screens/auth/Login"
import ForgotPassword from "../screens/auth/ForgotPassword"
import SignUp from "../screens/auth/SignUp";


const MenuNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  //Drawer Optons and indexing
  ForgotPassword: ForgotPassword,
  SignUp: SignUp,
},
  {
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    },
  }
);
export default MenuNavigator;
```

**AppNavigator**

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import StackNavigatorMain from "./StackNavigatorMain"
import MenuNavigator from "./MenuNavigator"


const AppNavigator =  createStackNavigator(
  {
    StackNavigatorMain: StackNavigatorMain,
    MenuNavigator: MenuNavigator
  },
  {
    headerMode: "none",
    navigationOptions: {
      headerVisible: false
    },
    initialRouteName: "StackNavigatorMain"
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

**Call openDrawer**

```
onLoginClicked = () => {
    props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Opening drawer from React-navigation v3 is called like this piece of code

```
this.props.navigation.openDrawer();
```

EDIT:
I tried to minimally replicate this using react-navigation v3
https://snack.expo.io/@keysl183/basic-drawer-v3

Comment: it return error: "this.props.navigation.openDrawer() is not a function"

Comment: How do you call the onLoginClicked ? Can you also share it?

Comment: just a onPress button

Comment: Do you call that on a header? or in a screen component?

Comment: I call in screen component

Comment: It would be helpful to also include that, on the side note, react-navigation has 3 versions already. Each has different approach. Which one do you use/

Comment: I'm using react-navigation": "^3.12.1"

Comment: I don't know why I create DrawerNavigator in AppNavigator it will work. But when I separate MenuNavigator like my code above it didn't open drawer.

Answer (score 0):

First get the reference of the navigator from top level component like this:

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

return <AppContainer ref={navigatorRef => Navigation.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef)} />;
```

In `Navigation.js` file you need to set a global variable for navigator reference :

```
let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
    _navigator = navigatorRef;
}
```

Then create function there like this:

```
function openDrawer() {
    _navigator.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())
}
```

Do not forget to import them:

```
import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation';
```

After that export them from `Navigation.js` file:

```
export default {
    setTopLevelNavigator,
    openDrawer,
}
```